# Electron send blob from main to renderer

Tags: electron

Trying to fetch an image from an API in the main process and send it as a blob back to the renderer process (as a user's action callback).

preload.js:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    getImage: async (name) => {
        const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('fetch_image', name);
        return result;
    },
});
```

main.js:

```js
ipcMain.handle('fetch_image', async (_ev, name) => {
    const res = await fetch(`....`).then(res => res.blob());
    return res;
});
```

When the `electron.getImage` function runs, it produces an error

`Error: Error invoking remote method 'fetch_image': Error: An object could not be cloned.`

I verified Node's global `fetch` returns blob successfully but it seems the blob can't be passed back?

I don't understand why that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make it work but I managed to do what I wanted with this workaround:

main.js

```js
ipcMain.handle('fetch_image', async (_ev, name) => {
    const response = await fetchImage(name);
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const arr = [];
    
    return reader.read().then(function collectChunks({ value: chunk, done }) {
        arr.push(chunk);
        if (!done) return reader.read().then(collectChunks);
        return arr.filter(Boolean);
    });
});
```

preload.js

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    getImage: async (name) => {
        return ipcRenderer.invoke('fetch_image', name);
    },
});
```

client component

```js
async function clickCallback(ev) {
    const bytes = await window.electron.getImage(ev.target.value);
    const blob = new Blob(bytes);
    // ...
}
```